# How to retrieve messages in dead letter topic for maual fix in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

The project i am working on has to route messages to kafka topics based on the field 'topic' in the message. When this routing fails for some reason such as the 'topic' field is empty I send messages to a dead letter topic for manual fix. Is there a possibility to retrieve a single or list of messages so that they can be fixed manually?

Found that I have to write another @KafkaListner, which listens to dead-letter-topic and processes the message. Here the problem is I need to fix them manually.

Comment: You need to write a consumer to read your dead letter topic , yes. Not sure I understand the problem

Comment: how do i manually edit each message after reading through consumer

Comment: Kafka records are immutable. You can use Kafka Streams map method, or you would need to link your consumer to a ProducerFactory sender

Comment: Regarding "routing" - you might want to look at Kafka Streams branch method

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is some kind of `console` application to handle DLT messages.

The simplest way I can think of is having a `@KafkaListener` that listens to the DLT and persists the records to a database. Then you can have an endpoint to `GET` these messages.

You would have another endpoint where you can `POST` or `PUT` the fixed record, or perhaps only `PATCH` the necessary fields. Note that Kafka records are `immutable`, so you'll be in fact creating a new record and sending it. Also, make sure you validate the new record properly against the original so you won't be prone to manual mistakes.

Of course, this would all be better with a proper frontend to make handling easier.

Comment: Understood that now. But just wondering, if i have an spring application is it possible to consume a single record from that DLT using kafkalistener instead of all the records at once?

Comment: You should be able to achieve that by using `pause`, `seek` and `resume` methods in the `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` class, along with setting `max.poll.records` to 1.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot listen to DLT message by adding @KafkaListener, it's not going to work. The correct annotation is @DltHandler